# Информация не вносится в базу данных при регистрации

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, авторизация, регистрация

Есть такая проблема, что при регистрации и создании аккаунта в базу данных ничто не вносится, а просто происходит редирект на следующую страницу. Я так полагаю, что ошибка в этой части кода.

```
        // Create account
    $createUserAccount_stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO info_users (email, username, password, sessionToken, referralID, ipAddress) VALUES (:email, :username, :password, :sessionToken, :referralID, :ipAddress)");
    $createUserAccount_stmt->bindParam(':email', $userEmail);
    $createUserAccount_stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $createUserAccount_stmt->bindParam(':password', $userPassword);
    $createUserAccount_stmt->bindParam(':sessionToken', $newSessionToken);
    $createUserAccount_stmt->bindParam(':ipAddress', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    if(isset($_COOKIE["referralID"])) {
        $createUserAccount_stmt->bindParam(':referralID', $_COOKIE["referralID"]);
    } else {
        $createUserAccount_stmt->bindParam(':referralID', $referralBase);
    }

    $createUserAccount_stmt->execute();

    // Redirect to dashboard
    header("Location:dashboard.php");
```

Comment: А не судьба проверить что возвращает вызов метода execute()?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov это довольно бессмысленная операция. РНР прекрасно сообщит обо всех проблемах без всяких дополнительных проверок. Его надо только попросить.